# reset default perldoc viewer

Tags: perl, pageviews, perldoc

I am learning perl now and I find perldoc a very handy tool.

Originally perldoc use 'less' as default page viewer. That's fine.
But recently perldoc use 'more' as default page viewer.

the phenomena:
1. man still use 'less'.
2. env | grep -Ei 'perl|view|man' gives no clue.

I read `perldoc perldoc` but I do not know what wrong had I done in the past that lead to this frustrated situation.
My requirement maybe seems silly: how could I restore default perldoc viewer, namely 'less'?

I use archlinux i686, openbox, xterm.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
export PAGER=/usr/bin/less -IJKMRW --shift 5
```

How perldoc perls the docs is doced in [perldoc perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html#ENVIRONMENT).

Comment: How many perldocs would a perldoc doc if a perldoc could doc docs?

Comment: thanks. but I was curious what config was massed up.I just cannot figure it out. I did not remember that, anything I have changed regarding this :(